# Erro: "Call to undefined function mysqli_init"

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou fazendo um teste com o framework codeigniter 3.1.5 e ao tentar conectar com o banco de dados ela apresenta o seguinte erro:

***Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()***

A descrição do erro completo:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

in                                                                                  C:\vm\ci\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php on line 135

A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 135

Backtrace:

Quero muito saber onde estou errando! O meu cenário e bem simples:

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- PHP 5.6.1 instalado
- Usando o servidor embutido do PHP `php -S localhost:8080`
- MySQL instalado na versão 5.7.18 porta 3309

O código de configuração do CI databese:

```
    active_group = 'default';
    $query_builder = TRUE;

    $db['default'] = array(
   'dsn'    => '',
   'hostname' => 'localhost',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => 'root',
   'database' => 'blog',
   'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
   'dbprefix' => '',
   'pconnect' => TRUE,
   'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
   'cache_on' => FALSE,
   'cachedir' => '',
   'char_set' => 'utf8',
   'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
   'swap_pre' => '',
   'encrypt' => FALSE,
   'compress' => FALSE,
   'stricton' => FALSE,
   'failover' => array(),
   'save_queries' => TRUE,
   'port'=>'3309'
     );
```

Quero saber o que esta errado ai?

Comment: Mysqli esta ativo no php.ini ?

Comment: @Otto Sim esta!
Ele exibe a seguinte mensagem no CLI: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll' - Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br /> 



A DLL esta na pasta ext junto com o php na minha maquina fica assim:


C:\php5\ext

Comment: Então só pela mensagem identificamos que ele ta tentando buscar no path errado seria interessante analisar isto. Mas ja identificamos que não é um problema no CI e sim configuração do php

Comment: Otto, consegui resolver aqui já na verdade era bem simples, era só apontar no INI do php o caminho das extensões do PHP

Comment: Se alguém tiver esse problema no futuro seja com o CI ou outra ferramenta fica a dica de olhar no INI do PHP a linha:

extension_dir= 'aqui você coloca o path das ext'


No meu caso ficou  

extension_dir = "C://php5//ext"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é um erro na sua aplicação.

Provavelmente esta falatando o driver msqli no php
Em seu php.ini e descomente o seguinte:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Se esse extensão estiver habilitada e apresentar o erro:
   ***Não foi possível localizar o modulo dessa extensão***

Verificar no INI do PHP a linha com a instrução `extension_dir` esse diretório aponta o path das extensions para serem carregadas, basta descomentar e colocar o caminha das extensions, segue trecho de como aparece no INI:

```
;Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
;http://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "./"
;On windows:
extension_dir = "C://php//ext"
```

No Windows o path deve ter sempre // ex: `c//php`

Obs: o comentario é representado pelo ponto e virgula( ";" )

Comment: Já havia feito isso, não resolve, sem conta que quando faço isso ele exibe a seguinte mensagem no CLI:
 PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll' - Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
 in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />

Comment: Tens que ter a Dll em sua máquina, não sei como é feito no windows. Mas tens que instalar essa extensão em seu php.

Comment: Verifica se voce tem o arquivo php_mysqli.dll na pasta php/ext/